# Save text data to array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm  very new to working with C#. I am trying to save data (text such as a persons name) which is entered into the console and then 'read' to an array.

The name of the array i want to save data to is: `name2convert`
The variable collecting the data (name to be converted) is: `nameEntered`

Any help is very much appreciated. I've been working on this for a few hours and have done several searches, but i have not found any answers which I could understand with my limited understanding of C# at this time. I've only been trying to learn this for a few weeks - i'm very very green. Any help is appreciated.

Note: String names was my test array so that i could see that i knew how to read data back from an array.

I want to save the data to the `names2Convert` array.

This is my code:

```
using System;

namespace a061___String_Manipulations___PigLatin
{
///loop - ask for number of names equal to number asked
///  read line, save to array, iterate one up until num equals value asked for

class Program
{
    //Arrays

    String[] names = { "test01", "test02", "test03", "test04", "test05" }; //Test loop

    String[] name2convert = new String[1];

    //Variables & Ints?
    string title = ">>>-- Welcome to the Highly Enlightening World of Igp-ay Atinl-ay --<<< \n";
    string totalIs = "You said you want to convert a total of";
    string listCommands = "Is that correct? If so type (Y)es, (R)enter or (Q)uit";// general commands used
    string addSuffix ="-ah!"; // Add to end of each name
    string nameEntered = "";//name to be converted

    int namesTotal = 0;//

    //Main Method
    public void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(title); //announce program

        askTotal(); //ask number of names

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listCommands);//lists options
            String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();//reads user command

            if (command == "y") // if askTotal true save to array? how?
            { 
                askName();//collects name entered
                confirmName();//allows user to confirm spelling, etc.    

                //y save the array   nameEntered   name2convert
                //name2convert.Add(nameEntered);
                name2convert[0] = nameEntered;

                //confirm name 
                for (int i = 0; i < name2convert.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name Aquired: " + name2convert[i]);
                }
            }
            else if (command == "r")
            {
                askName();//asks name
            } 
            else if (command == "q")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cheers!"); break; //end
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry. Invalid Request");//try again
            }

            PrintList();//test array 
        }
    }

    //Helper Methods
    public void PrintList()//iterates through, prints names stored in array
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print List");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". " + names[i] + addSuffix);
        }
    }

    //iterates through, prints names stored in array
    public void askName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name: ");//Confirming
        String nameEntered = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();// Capture name

        Console.WriteLine("Name Captured: " + nameEntered);//confirming name caught
    }

    //iterates through, prints names stored in array
    public void confirmName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(listCommands);//Confirming
        String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }

    //how many names to convert
    public void askTotal() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many names would you like to convert?");//Ask for content
        namesTotal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(totalIs + " " + namesTotal);//Confirming
    }

    //Call Application
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program StringManipulations = new Program();
        StringManipulations.Play(); //Call forth the Pig Latin...

        Console.Read();//
    }
}
```

}

Comment: arrays have a defined length.  use List<string>  or similar.

Comment: i didnt understand what data you want to sabe in namesToConvert? can you be more clear what are the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
//y save the array   nameEntered   name2convert
name2convert.Add(nameEntered);
```

To this:

```
name2convert[0] = nameEntered;
```

**EDIT:**

In `askName()` function change:

```
String nameEntered = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();// Capture name
```

To:

```
nameEntered = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();// Capture name
```

You already have `nameEntered` of type `string` declared as property of your class.

And why are you using `string` and then `String`? it's the same, as `string` is alias of `String` (which is in fact `System.String` in C#) - but be consistent!

As you already allocated the memory for this array (it's fixed size - in your case it's one).
So to access the first (and only) cell in your array, you should use `name2convert[0]` - 0 is the first index at any array and usually at any other struct/container in C# (and many other programming languages).

Another approach (as you were trying in your example) is to user `List<String>` instead.
For more information on arrays and Lists refer to here:

[Array tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[List tutorial and examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Comment: Thank you for the advice Etaiso, you are so very kind and I am so very thankful. I attempted your solution, but I fear I did something wrong. I have amended my code above to show how I revised it. ' name2convert[0] = nameEntered;

                    //confirm name 
                    for (int i = 0; i < name2convert.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Name Aquired: " + name2convert[i]);
                    }' This procuced no errors, so that is good, but It does not appear to have saved to the array.

Comment: Where did you put the for loop? right after the array assignment?
Are you sure that 'nameEntered' was changed? (got input from user)?

It's hard to tell as your Main receives user inputs that affect the program flow, and you didn't give us that input.

Comment: I believe that the method 'askName' captures the name as 'nameEntered' which i'm trying to save to the names2convert array.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help. I learned a lot and I look forwards to learning more. Again super thank etaiso, I feel like i'm back on track and have a fighting chance with the assignment. Now i just need to figure out how to set the array up to take any number of names given/entered by the user. Again - super thank you for your help and kindness!

Comment: I will let you figure it out by yourself :)
HINT: name2convert = new String[sizeOfArray];

Answer (score 0):

If you want save EVERY WORD that the user inputs use an List of Strings e.g

```
 List<String> name2convert;
```

then

```
name2convert.Add(nameEntered);
```

to go through the list

```
foreach (String word in name2convert) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, I will try/explore this. Thank you for the help/guideance. its' very much appreciated.